# TeamCity clean git checkout ubuntu reset file permissions

Tags: git, ubuntu, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity 7 with "clean all files before build" checked.

As part of the build steps, I need to run a shell script (.sh file), meaning I need to user to have an execute permission. I've tried using setfacl to change the permissions, but I cannot find a way to change the default mask, so it won't be reset when I run a build.

```
setfacl -Rm u:myuser:rwx,d:m:rwx path/folder
```

After I run this command, I can see the file's permissions were changed, but running a new build via TeamCity reset it back (The mask) to rw- instead of rwx.

**UPDATE**

The problem was fixed by setting the relevant .sh files with executable (git):
[image]

Comment: Alright, the problem was fixed. It turns out I had to mark the file as "executable" on git level (using Tortoise Git). That made the "error=13, Permission denied" go away. Writing it here so hopefully it would help someone else.